# Decrypt challenge in Salesforce from external system in 2FA

Tags: apex, oauth, decrypt

We are integrating salesforce with external system. External system has two factor authentication process.

1. We are calling first URL to get challenge. - Working fine.
2. We need to decrypt challenge in step2. We have an issue to decrypt the challenge, the error is:

   > "Invalid parameter exception, private key must have 16 bytes" .

   ```
   String challenge = 'NdqeqeqYQVyWaq0jYyB71Odhog==';
   blob challenge1 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(challenge);
   String mkey = 'zxvfg12';// client ask to convert into 16bytes but salesforce doesn't support.
   blob base64key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(mpin);
   Blob decrypted = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', base64key, challenge1);
   system.debug('.......'+decrypted);
   String decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
   System.debug('......'+decryptedString);
   ```

Is it possible to decrypt in Salesforce?

Comment: That's not a 16 byte key. It's not even a valid base 64 string. Yes, you can decrypt in Salesforce, but you need the right key.

Comment: Sfdcfox, Yes that is not 16 byte key. We need to convert to 16 byte array . We are not able to convert in salesforce hence salesforce doesn't support byte data type.

Comment: We are requested customer to get 16 byte array. Please see below                   String challenge = 'XF9kkKtLbjYgkub2Dv7Esg==';
blob challenge1 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(challenge);
blob base64key = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('UGFzczEyAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');
Blob decrypted = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128',base64key,challenge1);
system.debug('.......'+decrypted);
String decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
System.debug('......'+decryptedString);// Result is Empty string

Comment: Please edit your question with any additional information or clarification rather than posting in comments.

Comment: Any time encryption is in use, it is *critical* to be precise about how the encryption is being performed. You need to have the right key in the right format, use the matching algorithm and cipher mode, supply the initialization vector as expected by `decryptWithManagedIV()`, and so forth. If you don't know any of those factors, you need to go find out from the source system.